# Using "too" at the end of the sentence

Tags: grammaticality

For example "You are my favorite person too." Is this correct? Or should I say "You too are my favorite person."

Comment: You could say both and have two sentences meaning different things. "You are my favourite person too" means a certain person is, in addition to other things, also your favourite person. "You too are my favorite person" means a certain person, in addition to other persons, is also your favourite person.

Comment: "You too are my favourite person" doesn't make sense. I think that the most reasonable interpretation of that wording is what @Stockfish said, but *person* is singular so you can't have two (or more) people as your favourite person. (If there is a tie for favourite person you would say "one of my two favourite people".)

Comment: In speech it’s common and idiomatic, when someone says “I love you,” to respond with “I love you too.” Also: “I like peppermint ice cream.” “I like it too.” These responses are friendlier versions of “I also love you” and “I also like it.”

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. They can have different meanings.

> You are my favorite person, too.
>
> *or*
>
> You are my favorite person too.

This adds to a previous statement. Perhaps the addressee had told the speaker that *he* was *his* favorite person. Or perhaps the speaker had said that the addressee is a third party's favorite person. Or it can mean the same as…

> You too are my favorite person.

This means that the addressee, in addition to someone already mentioned, is the speaker's favorite person. This would be highly unusual since people don't speak of different two people as "my favorite person" (they might say "among my favorite people").